# Excel VBA - ADO RecordSet returning row 2 as header row instead of row 1

Tags: excel, ado, recordset, vba

I am opening a connection to an Excel 2003 (.xls) worksheet using the following code:

```
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
With adoConn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & vendorSource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

adoRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
adoRS.CursorType = adOpenStatic
adoRS.ActiveConnection = adoConn
adoRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [6000_600_VENDOR_MAIN_INFO]"
```

This has properly returned results from the worksheet up until recently.  In the current spreadsheet that I am connecting to, the recordset is returning row 2 as the header row instead of row 1.  I am not sure what has changed in the spreadsheet.  Visually looking at the spreadsheet, it appears nothing is different except the cell formatting for the header row.  I tried clearing the formats for row 1, but it didn't make any difference.  What could be causing the recordset to return row 2 as the header row instead of row 1?

Something else to note is that I am making the connection from Excel 2007, but connecting to an Excel 2003 formatted spreadsheet.

TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: Is the query returning both rows or only row 2?

Comment: There are 1202 rows on the worksheet.  Row 1 is the column headers; row 2 starts the data.  The recordset is ignoring row 1 as far as i can tell and returning row 2 as the header row (recordset field names), then it returns all of the data starting from row 3.  It should be returning row 1 as the header row and row 2 as the start of data.

Comment: As for your question, if you are asking if the query is returning both row 1 and row 2 as the header row, how could I tell?  Referring to the header name (from row 1 of the worksheet) as a field name causes an error saying the field is not found.

Comment: Is `[6000_600_VENDOR_MAIN_INFO]` a named range or the name of the worksheet? If it's a named range, does it still include the headings?

Comment: @creamyegg: `6000_600_VENDOR_MAIN_INFO` is the name of the database. @Ashaelon: Have you verified in debug mode what was returned by your query, add a spy on your recordset?

Comment: Debug is where I found out that row 1 was being ignored because it failed trying to find a field name that I know exists.  This is the first time it has done this, so maybe there is something wrong with the spreadsheet itself.  Thank you for the responses, but I think I am just going to see if it does it on the next spreadsheet before I pursue this any further.

Comment: FYI - I just found the problem.  There is a named range named the same as the worksheet name.  I was not aware of this being there.  Thanks again for all of your responses.

Comment: @FrancisP sorry, how can it be a database?

Comment: @creamyegg: too early in the morning, I meant table. X)

Comment: Just for other people reading this, the fix to this was simple. I wanted the entire worksheet, so to get around the Named Range, which was named the same as the worksheet, I changed this: `adoRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [6000_600_VENDOR_MAIN_INFO]"` to: `adoRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [6000_600_VENDOR_MAIN_INFO$]"` _Note the $ at the end of the worksheet name_

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in the connection string:

HDR=YES;

That clause instructs the database driver to read the first row of your file as a list of column or field names.

Reccode it to:

HDR=NO;

There's additional documentation here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

The text driver page on ConnectionStrings.com has some interesting tips about IMEX=0 and other OLEDB apocrypha.

Comment: Ah. Just saw '5 more comments' and your note about a named range with the same name as your source worksheet. My tip would've worked... Badly.